# Use Datepicker For a Date Field

Tags: grails

I am using Grails 4.  My book domain has a date field. I use <f:all bean="book"/> in my edit view to display the input fields.  The Fields plugin displays 3 dropdown boxes with the day, month, and year in the html for the date field in the book.

Would you teach me how to display a Datepicker instead of popping up 3 dropdown boxes please?

Thanks!

Comment: Which datepicker would you like to use?

Comment: I guess it is the datepicker that comes with grails.  <g:datepicker> Thx!

Comment: "I guess it is the datepicker that comes with grails. <g:datepicker> Thx!" - I am surprised that isn't what you are getting.  If you file an issue at https://github.com/grails-fields-plugin/grails-fields/issues we can investigate.

Comment: Oh I see! you means the 3 drop down boxes are the <g:datepicker>?  Can you teach me how to replace grails datepicker with the bootstrap datapicker instead?  Something that will pop out a calendar for me to click.  thx!

Comment: "Can you teach me how to replace grails datepicker with the bootstrap datapicker instead? " - That wouldn't be easy to show in a comment.  If you post that as a new question you would likely get help.

Comment: Is there a grails native way to display a calendar for me to click instead of picking the date from 3 dropdown boxes?  Thx!

Comment: "Is there a grails native way to display a calendar for me to click instead of picking the date from 3 dropdown boxes?" - There isn't a default GSP tag for doing that, but you can use any JS library you like in a GSP, including Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I just review the bootstrap document. Bootstrap does not have any native datepicker. I should ask how to replace the grails datepicker with the jquery ui datepicker.